# monolithic flash photo gallery

Tags: images, flash, image-gallery, embedding

i need to do a presentation dvd of my photos, so i would like to make a nice flash gallery with my photos embedded inside flash files, so there is no way of stealing my shoots just browsing dvd folders. Inside a dvd i'll have plenty of space so i don't care about the size of the flash file itself. There is any way to do that? Because as far as i see, all the flash galleries uses an XML file to load the images from outside, so all the shoots are jpeg put in another folder, and anyone can take them just copying the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn them into pdfs, with the watermarking feature and just put those files on the disk, and write the xml file or whatever.

Comment: but i mean, basically if they can view your photos, they can hit the screenshot key.

Comment: I need to make a gallery, easily browserable with arrow, so pdfs are not a solution... and i know they could screenshot, but this is an harder stealing solution than the one of simply copying the photo from the folder

Comment: I'm tnot sure why pdfs are not a solution? could you elaborate?

Comment: it should be like a gallery from a website, where you can surf it freely, i want it like an exe that loads and let the customer surf freely, but if the custoemr try to explore the content of the disk i want him to not be able to lurk the images.